# Loading configuration data at deployment time in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am building a common module for Auditing. I have built the module such that the consumer application can configure the Beans and fields to be audited in a XML or by annotations (similar to general frameworks eg:OpenJPA). Now I want to know some best practices to load the configuration data.
I can load the configuration data - when the application that uses this common module is deployed.

Question : 
How should I start the loading process - should I load from a static block ?

Also please elaborate on how the frameworks like JPA etc.. initiate their configuration load.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: hi friends, I am still looking out for some suggestions - feel free to post your thoughts.

Comment: Answering my own question :) - We can use javaagent to achieve this. follow the below steps
1)Create a class with a static method agentmain(String args).
2)In MANIFEST.MF of the jar specify agent-class:<FQ class name>.
3)execute the jar "java -javaagent:agent.jar -cp com.Main"